# Store result of sparse matrix decomposition in pre-specified memory location, in Eigen

Tags: sparse-matrix, eigen

I am trying to write a function to perform a sparse Cholesky decomposition using the Eigen library, where I pass in both the pointers to the input matrix data and the pointers to where I want to store the output matrix.

The program is currently

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <Eigen/SparseCore>
#include <Eigen/SparseCholesky>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;


struct CSC {
    int *indptr;
    int *indices;
    double *data;
    int nnz;
};

int cholesky_sparse_d_c(struct CSC *A, struct CSC *L,
        int rows, int cols, int nnz) {
    // Find sparse Cholesky factorisation of matrix A and store in triangular
    // matrix L i.e A = L L.T.
    // First we must build the sparse matrix A.
    Map<SparseMatrix <double> > A_sp(rows, cols, nnz,
            A->indptr, A->indices, A->data);
    cout << "A: " << endl << A_sp << endl;

    // Now compute the sparse Cholesky decomposition.
    SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double> > SLLT;
    SLLT.compute(A_sp);
    if (SLLT.info() != Success) {
      cout << "Decomposition failed";
      return -1;
    }
    cout << "Sparse lower factor of A:" << endl << SLLT.matrixL()
         << endl;

    // Put the values back into L. Note I am not sure if we need to create a
    // `temp` variable here, as the call `.matrixL()` may be free.
    SparseMatrix<double > temp(SLLT.matrixL());
    L->indptr = (int *) temp.outerIndexPtr();
    L->indices = (int *) temp.innerIndexPtr();
    L->data = (double *) temp.valuePtr();
    L->nnz = (int) temp.nonZeros();
    Map<SparseMatrix <double> > L_sp(rows, cols, L->nnz,
            L->indptr, L->indices, L->data);
    cout << "L: " << endl << L_sp << endl;

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct CSC A;
    int A_indptr[] = {0, 1, 2};
    int A_indices[] = {0, 1};
    double A_data[] = {1.1, 2.2};
    A.indptr = A_indptr;
    A.indices = A_indices;
    A.data = A_data;

    struct CSC L;

    cholesky_sparse_d_c(&A, &L, 2, 2, 2);

    cout << L.indptr[0] << L.indptr[1] << L.indptr[2] << endl;
    cout << L.indices[0] << L.indices[1] << L.indices[2] << endl;
    cout << L.data[0] << L.data[1] << L.data[2] << endl;
}
```

As mentioned in the code, I am not sure if the `temp` variable is necessary as

```
    L_indptr = SLLT.matrixL().outerIndexPtr();
    L_indices = SLLT.matrixL().innerIndexPtr();
    L_data = SLLT.matrixL().valuePtr();
```

may be fine (I am not sure if `matrixL()` is a free operation).

Regardless, when this function exits the memory that the `L` pointers were pointing to will now be free'd. I could copy the memory but this is unnecessary and inefficient. What I would ideally like to do is tell `SLLT` to not create new pointers for

- `.outerIndexPtr()`
- `.innerIndexPtr()`
- `.valuePtr()`

but to use the pointers in the `L` structure provided.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on saving a copy (it should be very cheep compared to the decomposition), then the simplest and safest would be to keep `SLLT` alive as long as your `L`, for instance by creating a small structure storing both objects and being responsible for destroying both of them.

Otherwise, you could imagine *moving* `SLLT.matrixL()` into `L`, but then you'll have to free the allocated memories, but you cannot as you don't know how it was allocated. To allocate yourself `L` and pass it `SLLT`, you need a way to exactly know the number of non-zeros in `L`. Actually, this information is computed by the `analyzePattern` step, but this method also pre-allocate `SLLT.matrixL()`, so that's too late.